# How to integrate my Amazon web services(aws) lex bot to any website

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex

I had done research on how to integrate aws-lex chatbot to an external website.
How can I find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [aws-lex-web-ui](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui) github repo. It provides a chatbot UI component that can be integrated in your website.